# How to parse json file to dictionary

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

i want parse a json file to Dictionary and want write some data to it.
this is what i have, but i become a empty Dictionary

```
var users = {};

      fs.readFile('login.json', function read(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        users = JSON.parse(data);
      });
```

Comment: Python has dictionaries, JavaScript has objects.

Comment: try with `fs.readFile('login.json', {encoding: 'utf8'}, function...`

Comment: How do you know it is empty? You have no code in your example to test it.

Comment: What is the content of `login.json`?

Comment: @hgoebl No, my object is empty...

Comment: I haven't asked a question. And what is your "object"? You could read the API docs and insert some lines of `console.log` and show us the output.

Comment: console.log("Parsed Data: "+users);

Output:
Parsed Data: [object Object]

console.log("Vorher "+Object.keys(users).length);
Output:
Vorher 0

Comment: @Axel0nf1r3 — Please edit your question to show us how / when you are running that code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Node.js you can require JSON files, so your code could simply become:

```
var users = require('./login.json');
```

Though note the data will be cached, so if your login.json file changes without an application restart the users object will stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

`readFile` is an asynchronous function. If you want to do anything with the data in it, you must do so in the callback function (or at some point after you know the callback has been run).

You may want to use [`readFileSync`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options) instead.